# Translate Shipping Method Title in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom shipping module following the below two tutorials

http://techportal.inviqa.com/2011/06/09/creating-a-custom-magento-shipping-method/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module

I now need to translate the shipping method title, however, I am getting the following error

```
Invalid method VMR_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Customrate::__(Array
    (
        [0] => Flat Rate: 3-10 Days
    )
)
```

using this line of code

```
$optionTitle = $this->__('Flat Rate: 3-10 Days');
```

Any ideas or input is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `__()` function is defined in the abstract classes of core block, core controller and core helper, but not core models. You can easily translate anything you wish by setting up a helper that extends `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract` and run that function.

`echo Mage::helper('vrm_shipping')->__('Flat Rate: 3-10 Days')`

... or if you're feeling lazy, just get the abstract helper to translate for you

`echo Mage::helper('core')->__('Flat Rate: 3-10 Days')`

...However, I'm not sure the specifics of what you're doing, but generally it is best practice to translate within the block or templates themselves. Why don't you call the `__()` function in the template that outputs the shipping methods instead?